# Shared Library undefined symbol

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dlopen

Similar title question exist but not the same problem . 
I have two machines one with **CentOS 7.3.1611** and one with similar to CentOS you can say **custom RedHat** .
i have a SDK that i need to run on the custom machine but it doesn't have **yum gcc**.
so i had to compile and install the SDK on CentOS, after that i copied the result to the custom machine (shared libraries, scripts , binaries ...) in Order to run them there .
Naturally the SDK worked fine on CentOS, but on the custom machine while loading some of the drivers and other libraries fine , i got an error when loading a specific library as follow :

> dlopen (libsdkpolicerlib.so) failed: (/usr/local/bin/../lib/libsdkpolicer.so.1: undefined symbol: policer_validate_packet_type)

Notice there are three shared objects involved here :

- **libsdkpolicerlib.so** the one that dlopen tries to open
- **libsdkpolicer.so.1**
- **libpolicercomlib.so** that contains the symbol policer_validate_packet_type

all of the shared object are in the same directory **/usr/local/lib** .
**libpolicercomlib.so** actually contains the symbol .

I have :

- verified the ld.so.cache contains all of the above libraries .
- Also i have added /usr/local/lib to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable .
- Executed ldconfig with "-n" with the path ...

I know this isn't the best way to do this sort of stuff, but this solution is temporary .

My question is what else do i have to verify in order for this to work ?
What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check /lib/libsdkpolicer.so.1 with ldd command, maybe the libpolicercomlib.so file which you copy just is a link file, and check it on your machine without yum GCC. If everything is correct， you can copy the /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 loader from your complie machine to your new machine(backup it before) and try it.

Comment: Thanks. there were some problems with symlinks . i just verified with tar to preserve symlinks and cp with -P .

Comment: Copying `ld-linux` from one machine to another is the *worst* possible advice ever. Either the original and the source are identical, in which case the operation is a no-op, or they are not, in which case the copied to machine will become trashed -- literally no commands will work -- and will require restoring from a rescue disk.